# How would I group by unique values that are in a list form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

If I wanted to get the mean of the past 2 values based on column `id`, I would do the following:

```
df['rolling_mean_2'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2, min_periods=2).mean())

>>      id   value  rolling_mean_2
   0    b    1      NaN 
   1    b    3      2
   2    d    5      NaN
   3    d    7      6
```

Right, straightforward.
Ok, now  let's say my id are in a list form with 4 unique values *(a, b, c, d)*

```
 x = [{'id': ['a','b','d'], 'value':1},
      {'id': ['b','a','d'], 'value':3},
      {'id': ['b','a','d'], 'value':5},
      {'id': ['a','b','c'], 'value':7}]

 df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Now, how would I get the mean from the past 2 values (incl. current row) based on unique value that contains in the list? Thus, my expected output would be as follows:

> I'm only going to use variable **a** and **d** to keep tidiness and simplicity.

```
>>          id          value      a_rolling_mean_2      d_rolling_mean_2   
      0     [a, b, d]   1          NaN                   NaN
      1     [b, a, d]   3          2                     2          
      2     [b, a, d]   5          4                     4
      3     [a, b, c]   7          6                     NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `concat` with dataframe constructor recreate the dataframe

```
df=df.rename(columns={'value':'V'})
newdf=pd.concat([df.V,pd.DataFrame(df.id.tolist(),index=df.index)],axis=1)
```

Then , Using `melt` with `groupby` `rolling` `mean` and `stack` to get the out put

```
newdf.reset_index().melt(['index','V']).set_index('index').sort_index().groupby('value').V.rolling(2, min_periods=2).mean().unstack(0)
Out[260]: 
value    a    b   c    d
index                   
0      NaN  NaN NaN  NaN
1      2.0  2.0 NaN  2.0
2      4.0  4.0 NaN  4.0
3      6.0  6.0 NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much